# Using if statement with jquery keydown function

Tags: jquery, html

I am a complete beginner in jquery.

I'm trying to figure out how I can do an if statement with this code

```
$("#Email").keydown(function() {
        $("#email-confirmation").fadeIn("slow");
        $("input[type=email]").css('border','1px solid #093');
});
```

I want to do something like this. If the input field have any value (user started typing), do something and if it is empty, do another thing ...

```
if ($("#Email").keydown(function() ) {
        $("#email-confirmation").fadeIn("slow");
        $("input[type=email]").css('border','1px solid #093');

}else{
        $("#email-confirmation").fadeOut("slow");
        $("input[type=email]").css('border','1px solid gray');

});
```

**I also need to know how to fadeIn or Out a css style with jquery**

Thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `keyup` i.e., after key has been released:

```
$("#Email").keydown(function() ) {
  if ($(this).val().length) {
     $("#email-confirmation").fadeIn("slow");
     $("input[type=email]").css('border','1px solid #093');
  } else {
     $("#email-confirmation").fadeOut("slow");
     $("input[type=email]").css('border','1px solid gray');
  }
});
```

Comment: does  if ($(this).length)  means if it has "any" length ?

Comment: @Mazen it is `$(this).val().length`. It means its  not empty and have some value. You can also use `$(this).val().trim().length` to ignore trailing/leading whitespaces.

Comment: the first part works fine, but when i delete what i wrote (empty field), it doesn't fade out

Comment: it worked when i changed keyown with keyup as you mentioned. However, I wish I can understand why keyup worked and key down didn't :(

Comment: @Mazen Keydown is called before realising the key and keyup after. So if you check for element's value with these two then it will differ. For more information see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Put the `if` inside the function:

```
$("#Email").keydown(function() ) {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $("#email-confirmation").fadeIn("slow");
        $("input[type=email]").css('border','1px solid #093');
    } else {
        $("#email-confirmation").fadeOut("slow");
        $("input[type=email]").css('border','1px solid gray');
    }
});
```